# Float and Double NaN (Not-a-Number) value

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, floating-point, double-precision

I was reading [`JLS8 4.2.3`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.2.3) there I found concept for `Float NaN` and `Double NaN`. When I opened the source code of `Float` and `Double` class, and tried following code:

```
1st condition:
if (Float.NaN == Float.intBitsToFloat(0x7fc00000)) 
    System.out.println("Both are equal");
}

2nd condition:
if (Float.NaN == (0.0f / 0.0)) {
    System.out.println("Equal");
}
```

According to documentation: An NaN is

```
/**
 * A constant holding a Not-a-Number (NaN) value of type
 * {@code float}.  It is equivalent to the value returned by
 * {@code Float.intBitsToFloat(0x7fc00000)}.
 */
```

Then why my both conditions are `false`. And in eclipse for `2nd condition` I was getting `warning: Dead Code`.

Same thing with `Double NaN`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because floating-point defines `NaN == NaN` to be `false`.  (This makes sense; `0/0` and `acos(2)` are both `NaN`, but that doesn't mean that they're equal to each other in any useful sense.)

Use `Float.isNaN()` to determine whether something is `NaN`.

Comment: why I was getting `warning: Dead Code`?

Comment: @Vishrant: Because the compiler knows that comparison will never be true.  You'd get the same thing with `if (1 == 2) { ... }`.

Answer (score 3):

This is because NaN is, by definition, not equal to anything. It is used to model a something, and all we know about this something is that it is not a number.

Think of it like this: A chair is NaN, your screen is also NaN (not a number), yet, your chair is not the same as your screen.

Likewise, given that Jane is not your mother and John is not your mother, it makes no sense to insist that Jane and John must be the same person.

Comment: why I was getting `warning: Dead Code`?

Comment: Because Eclipse knows the above and can tell at compile time that the then branch will never be entered.

Answer (score 2):

As a complement to other answers, you *can* test whether a `float` is NaN using either of:

```
Float.isNaN(myFloat);
```

or:

```
Float.compare(Float.NaN, myFloat) == 0
```

The same is true for `Double.NaN`; and the `Double` class has a similar method.